# Overwrite template-files

Tags: templating, craft3

I want to use one template on several Craft websites (different installations, not multi-sites). Is there a way in Craft I can do something like this? I want to update/overwrite the /templates/core/ directory when I implement new features/elements in the template but on the other hand, I want to have the option, to overwrite single template-files without losing the changes with the next update.

A directory structure could look like this:

- templates/core/layout.twig
- templates/core/home.twig
- template/custom/home.twig

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

One possible way would be this:

**templates/core/home.twig**

```
{% include ['custom/home.twig', 'core/base/home.twig'] %}
```

**templates/core/base/home.twig**

```
Welcome!
```

**templates/custom/home.twig**

```
Willkommen!
```

Problem: For this approach, I would always need to create one file, which just calls this include. As I want to split down the template in a lot of small files, to have the option to overwrite the templates on a very low level, this would cause in maybe hundred extra files.

Is there anyway to do something like this:

**templates/core/home.twig**

```
{% includeOr 'custom/home.twig' %}
   Welcome!
{% endIncludeOr%}
```

**templates/custom/home.twig**

```
Willkommen!
```

Comment: Not sure I understand this properly but if I do, watch this video (in full) - https://vimeo.com/295001383

Comment: This a very "open" question, but generally speaking you can get a lot by dynamically including templates - either storing the template name in a Craft field and/or checking if  a custom template exists before falling back to the core template.

Comment: Thanks for the video @Oli. Will watch this!

Comment: @gioppe, I think what you describe, is exactly what I want to archive. I want to check, if there is a templates/custom/home.twig file. If yes: Load it, if not: load templates/core/home.twig. With twig's include its possible to check, if file X exists, otherwise use Y. But this brings another problem (please see my update).